# jQuery animate() repeats 3x

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, jquery-animate, dhtml

I'm trying to do a 3 stage animation, where the open box minimizes, they all slide left, and the clicked on box expands. The final animation, the selected box expanding, repeats 3x when it is called as an argument of the 2nd animation, but if I call it alone it works fine.

its hosted at http://st-catherineschool.org/xbox/

```
$("#box2").click(
    function(){
      box = 2;
      if(boxopen==box)return;
      $("#box"+boxopen).animate({height:"-=30%", width:"-=10%", top:"+=20%", fontSize:"14px"}, 500, null,
      function(){
        $("section").animate({right:"+=25%"},500,null,
        function(){
          $("#box"+box).animate({height:"+=30%", width:"+=10%", top:"-=20%"}, 500);
          $("#box"+boxopen).css("z-index", "8");
          $("#box"+box).css("z-level", "9");
          boxopen = box;
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you’re looking for [`jQuery#stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/), which stops any currently-running animation on the matched elements. Try calling `.stop()` before using `.animate()`, like this:

```
// instead of:
$('section').animate(…);
// try this:
$('section').stop().animate(…);
```

Comment: this is not an issue with stopping the animation, its an issue with the DOM Bubbling!

Comment: adding the .stop() changed nothing, and I dont think its bubbling because answer 1 didnt help either.

Comment: my bad you were right, you just put it with the wrong selector in your example. When I put it with ("#box"+box), AKA #box2, in the last function, it works how I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your HTML looks like, but it could be that your click is bubbling down to other elements and causing this behavior. To prevent this, use `stopPropagation()`

EX:

```
$("#box2").click(
    function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      box = 2;
      .....
```

Comment: the full page is at http://st-catherineschool.org/xbox/ but #box2 is an empty <section> in <body>

Comment: e.stopPropagation() changes nothing in the first function, but if i put it in the others the animation in those functions never happens